# Properly accessing imported namespaces when mocking in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm starting a new project in Python 3. I intend to make this a PIP package, so I've started with a cookiecutter template as follows:

```
cycle_calendar_generator
/cycle_calendar_generator
  __init__.py
  cycle_calendar_generator.py
/tests
  __init__.py
  test_cycle_calendar_generator.py
```

This project will be used widely in my school, so I want to do solid unit testing from the start. I'd rather stick with the Python3 included unittest modules, since they're simple and do what I want.

The problem is that I need to do some mocking of core API modules, like argparse and os. I've seen advice that you should mock the namespace of the core API module imported, not the module itself. (So mocking cycle_calendar_generator.argparse is correct, but importing argparse and mocking it is not, since it's a different copy of argparse.)

With that said, here's what I have in the test_cycle_calendar_generator.py:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from cycle_calendar_generator import cycle_calendar_generator


class Test_get_args(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for `cycle_calendar_generator` package."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Set up test fixtures, if any."""

    def tearDown(self):
        """Tear down test fixtures, if any."""

    @mock.patch('cycle_calendar_generator.argparse.parse_args')
    def test_if_arg_is_string(self, mock_parse_args):
        mock_parse_args.return_value = cycle_calendar_generator.argparse.Namespace(directory='string')
        self.assertIsInstance(cycle_calendar_generator.getArgs(), str)
```

This is giving me the error `AttributeError: module 'cycle_calendar_generator' has no attribute 'argparse'`, so it's clearly not finding the imported argparse, but I can't figure out how I might solve it. Any idea what could be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AttributeError: module 'cycle_calendar_generator' has no attribute 'argparse'

It should be:

```
@mock.patch('cycle_calendar_generator.cycle_calendar_generator.argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args')
```

Not

```
@mock.patch('cycle_calendar_generator.cycle_calendar_generator.argparse.parse_args')
```

Not

```
@mock.patch('cycle_calendar_generator.argparse.parse_args')
```

Comment: Now that's giving me this error: `AttributeError: <module 'argparse' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/argparse.py'> does not have the attribute 'parse_args'`

Comment: @ROldford, we do not normally mock or test the `argparse`, I updated the mock in case you still want to do it.

Comment: I actually got that earlier today, but thanks! Finally making progress thanks to your help.